# What is the best way to process large data in PHP

Tags: php, out-of-memory, large-data

I have a daily cron job which will get a XML from web service. Sometimes it is large, contains more than 10K products information and the XML size will be 14M example.

What I need to do is parsing XML to object then processing them. The processing is quite complicated. Not like directly put them into the database, I need to do a lot operation on them, and finally put them into many database tables.

It is just in one PHP script. I don't have any experience on dealing with large data.

So the problem is it take a lot of memory. And very long time to do it. I turn my localhost PHP memory_limit to 4G and running 3.5hrs then got successful. But my production host is not allowed such amount memory.

I do a research but I am very confused which is a right way to dealing with this situation.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
function my_items_import($xml){

    $results = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
    $results->registerXPathNamespace('i', 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/Item');

    //it will loop over 10K
    foreach($results->xpath('//i:Item') as $data) {

        $data->registerXPathNamespace('i', 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/Item');

        //my processing code here, it will call a other functions to do a lot things
        processing($data);

    }
    unset($results);
}
```

Comment: How are we supposed to help with processing if you haven't provided info about it? 14Mb xml file shouldn't generally be processed for 3.5 hours and take 4Gb of memory.

Comment: PS: 1. you're unsetting not existing variable 2. `unset` wouldn't change anything in your case

Comment: 10,000 records and 14Mb of data is not a large file. If you're using 4Gb memory to do a job in 3.5 hours you're almost certainly doing something very wrong.

Comment: I'm using drupal, and drupal commerce, I will using their functions. You know the CMS is slow already. The processing is too many code, it is hard to copy them here. Basically it need to check if product existing, update product info, catagery info, pricing info...

Comment: Is there a way to separate this task into smaller one?

Answer (score 3):

As a start don't use SimpleXMLElement on the whole document. SimpleXMLElement loads everything in the memory and is not efficient for large data. Here is a snippet from a real code. You'll need to accommodate it to your case but hope you'll get the general idea.

```
    $reader = new XMLReader();
    $reader->xml($xml);
    // Get cursor to first article
    while($reader->read() && $reader->name !== 'article');

    // Iterate articles
    while($reader->name === 'article')
    {
        $doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
        $article = simplexml_import_dom($doc->importNode($reader->expand(), true));
        processing($article);
        $reader->next('article');
    }
    $reader->close();
```

$article is SimpleXMLElement which can be processed further.
This way you save a lot of memory by making only single article nodes go into memory.
Additionally if each processing() function take long time you can turn it into a background process which runs in separately from the main script and several processing() functions can be started in parallel.

Comment: Thanks. Currently I think xml processing maybe is not the biggest problem. The processing function is taking too much. I'm interested in how to separately run this script. Like every time I only process 1K data but it will auto trigger the next 1K process. Always under the memory limit. Do you have some sample?

Comment: As you mentioned Drupal in one of your comments I would suggest to find a workaround without using the Drupal API or use some core functionality. After all Drupal is CMS and its primary intention is not running low level tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Key hints:

1. dispose data during process.

   - Dispose data - mean over write it with blank data. BTW, unset is slower than overwrite with null
2. Use functions or static method, avoid as much oop instance as possible.

One extra question, how long it takes to loop your xml without do [lots things]:

```
function my_items_import($xml){

    $results = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
    $results->registerXPathNamespace('i', 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/Item');

    //it will loop over 10K
    foreach($results->xpath('//i:Item') as $data) {

        $data->registerXPathNamespace('i', 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/Item');

        //my processing code here, it will call a other functions to do a lot things
        //processing($data);

    }
    //unset($result);// no need
}
```

Comment: If I do not processing data, it is only takes 80M memory. Near 3mins to get finish. Most of functions I will use are CMS API functions. It's hard to optimise them.

Comment: Too bad, if you can avoid to use CMS API, it might save your. I had same issue back ages with Magento, finial solution is touch the core code and write extension above it, avoid to use any of API, xml/soap api just way too slow.